Magento 2 revert an applied patch from Adobe commerce Cloud Environment
I applied a patch locally (adding the ‘QUALITY_PATCHES’ variable to the .magento.env.yaml file and listing the required patches underneath), and it was pushed to staging, where it was applied correctly in our Adobe Cloud Commerce staging environment.
Now, I want to revert it. I have successfully reverted it locally using the following command:
./vendor/bin/magento-patches revert MAGETWO-95591 MAGETWO-67097

However, there are no changes to push. How can I revert it from the staging environment?
Reference: Apply patches

You can remove the specific patch entry from the .magento.env.yaml

No it will revert the patch
